# Different domain causes issue in joomla module

Tags: joomla, module, dns

I have a strange issue. When added a new domain to my site, "latest news enhaced" module started to appear truncated, it does not show the calendar and has a different style. For your reference :  original installation http://myxolargos.gr/ilioupolis/ 
addon domain http://www.ilioupoli.gr/

I have tried to uninstall and install from new domain, but again it doesn't work properly in ilioupoli.gr It obviously has to do with a path somewhere?

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to this stylesheets, one for each module:

```
/ilioupolis/modules/mod_latestnewsenhanced/stylemaster_238.css
/ilioupolis/modules/mod_latestnewsenhanced/stylemaster_239.css
/ilioupolis/modules/mod_latestnewsenhanced/stylemaster_240.css
```

Removing them from the original install removes the css rules that handle calendar date and position of the green text (like the new install). So check this files in the new install and you will find the problem.

Comment: You're welcome, also consider to ask **Joomla related questions** on [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/) to get better answers!

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me before. What fixed the problem for me was to turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" off.

Navigate the site on the frontend, to the area affected.

Then turn "Search Engine Friendly URLs and Use URL Rewriting" on.

Comment: Τhank you, finally that did it. I had to wait a while to see the change, despite the fact I had cleaned the cache. (joomla + browser)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped out. It was driving me crazy, all while a client was breathing over me, when I had encountered the problem.